# Centre of mass of a quarter of disc (doubt in my solution)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, mass, geometry

Can please anyone tell where am i wrong in this approach of solving this question..
The ans i am getting is (4 root2)/pi but ans is (4 root2)/3pi

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your solution is that both $dx$ and $dy$ are integrated from $0$ to $R$, as if the object (i.e. its cross section) was a rectangle. In this particular example, it is much simpler to do the integration in *polar coordinates* than in Cartesian coordinates.

If you insist on Cartesian coordinates, then the correct integrals would be

$$x_\text{cm} = \frac{\sigma}{M} \int_{0}^{R} dy \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - y^2}} x dx = \frac{4 R}{3 \pi}$$

$$y_\text{cm} = \frac{\sigma}{M} \int_{0}^{R} dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}} y dy = \frac{4 R}{3 \pi}$$

where $M = \sigma R^2 \frac{\pi}{4}$ is total mass of the disc.

I show below how to find the center of mass in polar coordinates.

---

The center of mass is defined as

$$\boxed{x_\text{cm} = \frac{1}{M} \iiint_S x \cdot dm} \tag 1$$

where $M$ is total mass of the disc, $x$ is distance with respect to the *arbitrarily chosen* origin, and $dm$ is *infinitesimally small mass*. The idea is simple - sum distance $x$ of each (infinitesimally small) particle in the disc weighted (multiplied) by its mass $dm$ and then divide the sum by the disc total mass. Since disc in your question is homogeneous, i.e. its density $\rho$ is constant, and since cross section is constant throughout the depth of the disc, we can write:

$$dm = \rho \cdot dV = \rho \cdot h \cdot dA = \sigma \cdot dA$$

where $h$ is thickness (depth) of the disc. The total mass is $M = \sigma R^2 \frac{\pi}{4}$ and the Eq. (1) becomes

$$x_\text{cm} = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{1}{R^2} \iint_S x \cdot dA \tag 2$$

Now we have to express the infinitesimally small area $dA$. As I have already mentioned, the integration is much simpler in polar coordinates:

$$dA = (r+dr)^2 \frac{d\theta}{2} - r^2 \frac{d\theta}{2} = (2rdr + (dr)^2) \frac{d\theta}{2} \approx r dr d\theta$$

where $(dr)^2$ is neglected being much (much!) smaller than $dr$. See figure below for an explanation how infinitesimal small area $dA$ was calculated.

[image]

The distance of the infinitesimally small area $dA$ in $x$ direction in polar coordinates is $x = r \cos\theta$ and the Eq. (2) is solved as

$$x_\text{cm} = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{1}{R^2} \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} r \cos\theta \cdot r dr d\theta = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{1}{R^2} \int_{0}^{R} r^2 dr \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos\theta \cdot d\theta = \frac{4R}{3\pi}$$

The procedure is similar for the $y$ direction - the distance in polar coordinates is $y = r \sin\theta$ and the Eq. (2) is solved as

$$y_\text{cm} = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{1}{R^2} \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} r \sin\theta \cdot r dr d\theta = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{1}{R^2} \int_{0}^{R} r^2 dr \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin\theta \cdot d\theta = \frac{4R}{3\pi}$$

The position of the center of mass for given disc is

$$\boxed{\vec{r}_\text{cm} = \frac{4R}{3\pi} \hat{\imath} + \frac{4R}{3\pi} \hat{\jmath} = \frac{4R}{3\pi} \sqrt{2} e^{j \pi / 4}}$$

---

In your question you mention that the correct solution has $\sqrt{2}$ term in $x$ and $y$ coordinates. This is only possible if you rotate the disc by $45^\circ$ clockwise, in which case the center of mass would be at

$$\vec{r}'_\text{cm} = \vec{r}_\text{cm} e^{-j \pi / 4} = \frac{4R}{3\pi} \sqrt{2} \hat{\imath} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad x_\text{cm} = \frac{4R}{3\pi} \sqrt{2}, \quad y_\text{cm} = 0$$

If this explanation with rotation is too abstract, try repeating the above procedure (integration) when $\theta$ goes from $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$ and you will get the same result. Since disc is now symmetrical with respect to the $x$ axis, we can conclude that $y_\text{cm} = 0$ even without doing the integration.